# How to enable className autocomplete on custom jsx tags (aka react components)?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to vscode but i've set up about all the things I need. One more thing that is quite missing is the autocomplete for `className` attribute on custom jsx tags (aka react `components`). It simply does not recommend anything when on a custom tag.

I've tried searching for any extension that does this but couldn't find any, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I know there is no way to show react attributes in autocomplete list for custom react tags.

But there is a way to add className attribute quickly by putting a dot and typing your class name then hitting tab. This will create the custom tag with the given class attribute.

[image: Demonstration: Adding react class attribute to custom jsx tag]

To do this, you need to configure Emmet extension (It is a built-in extension)

Add these lines to your VS Code User Settings (or Workspace Settings) file:

`"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,`

`"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" }`

If you are on Mac, you can quickly open the User or Workspace Settings file, by pressing

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and typing into the Command Palette: `>settings.json`.

[image: vscode_settings]

[Official Documentation at VS Code Web Site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

[Related Issue on VS Code Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4962#issuecomment-321905708)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. On Windows, the command to open the  User or Workspace Settings file, by pressing Shift + Control + P and typing settings.json into the Command Palette. Be sure to select Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) because there are other similar options.

Comment: Ain't there a method to get autocompletion for classNames ?